# expo-image-picker: app shows all photos even if I choose the "selected photos" permission - iOS 14.0+ only

Tags: react-native, expo, ios14, react-native-image-picker

I am using the expo-image-picker for photo management. When I choose the "selected photos" permission and open the photo library, photo library shows all photos regardless it's permission status(selected photos).
This is happening in iOS14.0+ only.

is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing the same thing, have you found a solution heltdev?

Comment: Any solutions heltdev & Duver Arthur?